# Is there a way to retrieve a value from a merge statement?

Tags: sql, merge, db2

Good day everyone,

is there a way to retrieve a value from a merge statement? Imagine the following scenario. You have a table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz.PEOPLE ( 
  "ID" INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
    MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 1000 
    NO CYCLE NO ORDER 
    CACHE 20 
  ), 
  NAME VARCHAR(50) CCSID 1208 NOT NULL
);
```

Now you want to insert a person into the table. So you develop a REST-Service which uses JSON to feed your SQL-Statement with data. Finally you came up with a put method which invokes this statement:

```
merge into
  xyz.people as p
using
  (select cast(null as int) as id, 'John Doe' as name from sysIbm.sysDummy1) as n --(this is actually parsed JSON so just focus on NULL not on the cast)
on
  (n.id = p.id)
when matched then update set
  p.name = n.name
when not matched then insert (name)
  values(n.name);
```

If you would use the statement below you would retrieve the ID and the name.

```
select *
  from final table(
    insert into xyz.people (name)
      values ('John Doe')
  );
```

So my question is, is there a way to do so with a merge statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your Db2 server runs on Z/OS, then YES you can select from final table with MERGE.  But for Db2-LUW (Db2 server running on Linux, Unix Windows), this is not yet supported.   This is a frequently asked question.

Comment: Does it work also in a DB2/400 database? I tried but it doesnt worked out well.

Comment: It's not supported currently in DB2 for IBM i. See the `data-change-table-reference` part description of [table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafztabref.htm) of `sub-select`.